# How to retrive Property Name using DisplayName?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public class DoctorInfo    
{
     [DisplayName("form1[0].P1[0].Physician-Name[0]")]
     public string ProviderFullName { get; set; }
}
```

How can i get Property Name "ProviderFullName" programmatically if i have its DisplayName in hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate the properties and custom attributes -

```
 PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(DoctorInfo).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
            {
                object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(true);

                foreach (object attr in attrs)
                {
                    DisplayNameAttribute displayName = attr as DisplayNameAttribute;
                    if (displayName != null)
                    {
                       var attributeName = displayName.DisplayName; // check if this matches what you want
                    string propertyName = prop.Name;                        }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the `DisplayName` you can [get all the PropertyInfo members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties) in the class, then iterate over those to see if any of those has a `DisplayName` attribute using [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes).

If the `DisplayName` matches, then use the `MemberInfo.Name` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.name) to get the name back.